# XSLT set empty to xsl value of

Tags: xslt-2.0

How to set  to a empty value.
I have a

```
                <td>
                 <xsl:value of select=""> 
               </td>.
```

That td should contain an empty value.

Comment: please elaborate the case..what if you add following line in template <td></td> you  dont include <xsl:value of select=""> .This should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply that is working but I am missing the border for the td in that case which I gave thus effecting the design quiet a bit.

Comment: Simply use CSS in your HTML with `<style>table { emtpy-cells: show; }</style>`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/empty-cells. If you really want to put a text node with a space into a cell then use `<td><xsl:value-of select="'&#160;'"/></td>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `<td>&nbsp;</td>`

Comment: Ok.. `&` has special meaning and you have to escape that. Use `<td>&amp;nbsp;</td>`

Comment: &nbsp; . I am getting this output in the td when I entered &amp;nbsp;

Comment: That is expected. When it is rendered, your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
<xsl:value-of select="''"/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).